# Do I have per-connection bandwidth throttling?

Tags: ssh, networking, rsync, scp

I'm seeing what I believe to be throttling *somewhere* in my connection.

- I can only get 13 MB/s per connection with scp.
- If I run two scp sessions, I get 13 MB/s per connection on both.

I'm using SuddenLink. This form of throttling only seems to affect SSH. BroadbandSpeedTest and Steam seem unaffected by the per-connection throttling. Is there a technology that can either

- help me diagnose the kind of throttling they're employing, if any.
- help me work around it. Perhaps something like NFS/Multiple SSH sessions, or the like? Anything that can utilize multiple SSH session to transfer a single file.

Answer (score 1):

SCP is simple tool to transfer files. It is not designed to have super performance. It has a lot of synchronization so the speed is heavily affected with Round Trip Time. It has also small buffers (basically 2048 B -- [source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L763)).

If you aim for performance, SFTP should be a better choice. If you aim for more performance, there is [HPN patch for OpenSSH](https://sourceforge.net/p/hpnssh/wiki/Home/) which should make use of another advanced techniques to get even higher speeds.